Per-app language preferences default strings XML
I'm implementing per-app language to learn how it works so I've created an app with this config:

res/values/strings.xml <-- (default english values)
res/values-it/strings.xml <-- (italian string translate)

I've followed the official guide and works fine adding just the
androidResources {
    generateLocaleConfig = true
  }

and creating the res/resources.properties file with the following content:
unqualifiedResLocale=ita

Side note: This default locale value required to build the app seems to be ignored by the way because the app still using the system default language.
PROBLEM: The system doesn't allow me to choose english because in the System app language settings I have only "system default" (that means italian in this device) and Italian (two of that, one specific for Italy and another generic that want a region selection).
WORKAROUND: Create the folder "values-en" and copy the default/english strings.xml file. This works fine, in the settings now there is English, but in the code now I have two cloned strings.xml files that should be update on every changes (ok not a big deal at the end).
QUESTION: There is a proper way to do this? Specify that the default strings.xml should be used as a selectable language or this is the way was intended to work?

Noticed exactly the same thing from this feature, only way so far for making this work has been the workaroung you mentioned. Luckily it seems that you don't need to copy the whole strings.xml with all the localizations to the values-en folder, it is enough to have an empty strings.xml resource file there as system is able to then use english localizations from the default resource folder
